# I am getting an error when i use a custom font in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Its a very basic RecyclerView list app with two TextViews and one ImageView that pulls data using an ArrayList class. It works. But I wanted to set a custom font with one of the TextViews. Where can i put the "Typeface code"?

Main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);


        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);





        ArrayList<AllList> list = new ArrayList<AllList>();


        list.add(new AllList("test","description",R.drawable.arrow));

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Adapter class

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AllList> list;
    Typeface ef;
    Context c;


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public View View;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            View = v;
        }
    }


    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<AllList> duas) {


        this.list = duas;
    }


    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);



        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


       TextView title = (TextView) holder.View.findViewById(R.id.title);
       TextView desc = (TextView) holder.View.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) holder.View.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


//        Typeface cfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts.h.ttf");
//        this.ef = cfont;
//
////        title.setTypeface(ef);

        title.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
        desc.setText(list.get(position).getDesc());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an error per say but i couldn't figure out where to put the Typeface code."  Typeface cfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts.h.ttf");"

Comment: What happens when you have it in `onBindViewHolder`??

Comment: We can try to guess what is happening, but nothing else without logcat. Have you put your ttf in assets folder? If yes, then rename your file to "fonts.h.ttf" to "font.ttf"... maybe the dot is breaking your code. Your logcat could make us able to help you!

Comment: make sure your `assets` folder contains file `yourfont.ttf` `Typeface cfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplication().getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    createFont();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    createFont();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    createFont();
}

public void createFont() {
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "roboto_light.ttf");
    setTypeface(font);
}
}
```

use this class in XML

```
 <CustomTextView
     android:id="@+id/title" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

Last where you have to use this textview just initialized like that and use it

```
CustomTextView title = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText("Enjoy!!");
```